# Python - Using Lat-long to find the distance of a point to the closest train station (another point)

Tags: python, python-2.7, distance, latitude-longitude, euclidean-distance

I have found the average central point of each LSOA area in London and want to calculate the distance from this point to the nearest tube station (also a lat-long point)

I need to do this in Python - any help would be welcome! I am new to Python and am not sure how to approach this

CSV called 'Data':

```
   LSOA time    lat  long
E01000907   51.5632  -0.1428
E01000908   51.5639  -0.14530
E01000909   51.5623  -0.149880
E01000912   51.5600  -0.155263
```

CSV called 'Tube':

```
Station Latitude    Longitude
Abbey Road  51.53195199 0.003723371
Abbey Wood  51.4907841  0.12027197
Acton   51.51688693 -0.267689952
Acton Central   51.50875778 -0.263430199
Acton Town  51.50307144 -0.280302701
Earls Court 51.49135667 -0.194313809
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/47534715/4800652

Comment: This may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude