# How to sort value of each row of data frame and return the sorted columns name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames with different rows,  dF1=(1098 x 2 column ) and 
df2=(1331 x2)  for example:

df1

```
       lat-2    long-2
R1  10.612811   46.265142
R2  10.604078   45.896510
R3  10.610205   45.727291
R4  10.606051   45.772968
R5  10.596646   46.517013
```

df2

```
       lat-1    long-1
G1  10.604065   45.896533
G2  10.612811   46.265142
G3  10.606051   45.772968
G4  10.610205   45.727291
G5  10.606747   44.772287
G6  10.619976   45.847164
G7  10.607682   45.477258
G8  10.784809   44.769609
```

with the help of [Get Nearest Point from each other in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534715/get-nearest-point-from-each-other-in-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I calculate the Euclidian distance between each Row of df1 and all Rows of df2, so **new_df** has (1089 x 1331).
new_df

```
            G1          G2         G3          G4           G5        G6           G7             G8
    R1  0.368713    0.000000    0.492220    0.537857    1.492867    0.418039    0.787901    1.505391
    R2  0.000026    0.368735    0.123558    0.169330    1.124226    0.051844    0.419267    1.141302
    R3  0.169353    0.537857    0.045865    0.000000    0.955010    0.120271    0.250046    0.973469
    R4  0.123581    0.492220    0.000000    0.045865    1.000681    0.075491    0.295714    1.019158
    R5  0.620524    0.252389    0.744104    0.789838    1.744755    0.670255    1.039814    1.757506
```

I want the result like this:

```
                    close
  R1          [G2,G1,G6,G3,G5,G4,G7,G8]
  R2          [G1, G6, ,,......]
  R3          [G4,...]
  R4          [G3,....]
  R5          [G2,G5,...]
  R6          [G2,G3,...]
  R7          [G4,...]
```

in other words, I want for each row of **new_df**  to sort value of columns in ascending order , finally return result like I want.

I could not use codes of [Get Nearest Point from each other in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534715/get-nearest-point-from-each-other-in-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I try to write like this:

```
def Closest(df):

    d=defaultdict(list)
    for x in (df.index):

        y=df.loc[str(x)].copy()
        M=y.tolist()

        Q=M.sort_val(ascending=True)
        p=Q.index

        d[x].appand(p)

     return (d)
```

my idea was like:

```
h=new_df.loc["R1"].copy()
h:

    G1     0.368713
    G2     0.000000
    G3     0.492220
    G4     0.537857
    G5     1.492867
    G6     0.418039
    G7     0.787901
    G8     1.505391
    Name: R3, dtype: float64

k=h.sort_values(ascending=True)
k.index
d={}
d['R']=k.index
```

so I wanted to create a dictionary which contains index R as key and list of ordered G as value.finally, I can make a data frame from this dictionary.
but when I write this function is sending ("'float' object has no attribute 'sort_val'", 'occurred at index G1') or  'float' object is not iterable.

I am a new programmer (beginner),

How can I correct my function to reach my goal OR
if my idea is totally wrong how can I have my result?

Comment: Do you have thresh for cutting off the distance ?

Comment: not now, I think I must have and my Professor will add it to my exercise in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the `rank` for your df, then sort the column name with the order of rank , and create a new `Series`

```
lst=[ [z for z,p in sorted(zip(df.columns.values.tolist(),x),key=lambda y: y[1])] for x in df.apply(lambda x : x.rank(),1).values.tolist()]


pd.Series(data=lst,index=df.index)
Out[1531]: 
R1    [G2, G1, G6, G3, G4, G7, G5, G8]
R2    [G1, G6, G3, G4, G2, G7, G5, G8]
R3    [G4, G3, G6, G1, G7, G2, G5, G8]
R4    [G3, G4, G6, G1, G7, G2, G5, G8]
R5    [G2, G1, G6, G3, G4, G7, G5, G8]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, Thank you, but can you tell me here P , refers to what? I `m the new programmer,  I understand sorted and rank what are their result but I don't get P or Z  here.